# How to route to different topic in file stream source connector based on the file content?

Tags: regex, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

```
name=my-filestream-connector
connector.class=FileStreamSource
tasks.max=1
file=D:/kafka/kafka/config/demo_file4.txt
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
topic=default-topic
transforms=routeToTopic
transforms.routeToTopic.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
transforms.routeToTopic.regex=(.*)(info|warn|error)(.*)
transforms.routeToTopic.replacement=$1
transforms.routeToTopic.topic.format=%s
```

this is the file stream source connector config.

whatever the content i'm writing to the file is produced to the default-topic only. i want to route topics based on the file content that contains info, error, warn.

Answer (score 0):

`RegexRouter` acts on topic names, not record content. For this, you will need to write your own custom transform to inspect data value, then override the SinkRecord topic property.

Alternatively, simply write Kafka Producer code to do the same; this is not a good use-case for Kafka Connect.